# How can I merge 2 modals into 1 using components with React / Redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-bootstrap

I have a signup modal that looks like:

[image]

and a login modal that looks like:
[image]

Right now, I have them as 2 separate React Components triggered from my NavBar as follows:

```
  <Nav pullRight className="navright">
    <NavItem eventKey={3} href="#">Stuff</NavItem>
    <NavItem eventKey={4} href="#">Blog</NavItem>
    <NavItem href="#" className={this.state.signedIn ? '' : 'hidden'}>{this.state.name}</NavItem>
    <NavItem eventKey={2} href="#" className={this.state.signedIn ? 'hidden' : ''}><SignupModal/></NavItem>
    <NavItem eventKey={1} href="#" className={this.state.signedIn ? 'hidden' : ''}><LoginModal/></NavItem>
  </Nav>
```

I'd like to combine them into one modal component (potentially called `AuthModal`) and that'll load the appropriate component that is selected.

I am using `react-bootstrap` if that matters. I'm new to React, so if something is unclear, please let me know and I'll clarify.

Thanks.

Comment: You need to combine the contents of SignupModal and LoginModal into a new component called AuthModal. Start with the render function and work your way to functionality. It's no different than any other react/DOM work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gonna give you an idea.

You can setup it this way.

```
const Modal = ({ auth }) => {
  if (auth) {
    return {
      <div>all your stuff here</div>
    }
  }
  return {
    <div>all your other stuff here</div>
  }
}
```

So you call you modal like `<Modal />` and if you need to be the auth one you do like `<Modal auth={true} />`

```
<Nav pullRight className="navright">
    <NavItem eventKey={3} href="#">Stuff</NavItem>
    <NavItem eventKey={4} href="#">Blog</NavItem>
    <NavItem href="#" className={this.state.signedIn ? '' : 'hidden'}>{this.state.name}</NavItem>
    <NavItem eventKey={2} href="#" className={this.state.signedIn ? <Modal /> : <Modal auth={true} />}></NavItem>
  </Nav>
```

Hope that can help ;)

Comment: This is great! Thank you. How can I pass a string instead of `true`?

Comment: You can pass a string `auth={'myString'}` and inside the component you can 

`if (auth === 'myString')`

Comment: I edit my answer for showing you how you can call it with your stuff.